# Will Reactive Extensions (Rx) supersede the Task Parallel Library?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, system.reactive

After following through the [samples of Rx.NET](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples), I'm gob smacked at how brilliant the concept and implementation of Reactive Extensions are. It appears to offer developers a more maintainable pattern for achieving the same sort of multi-threaded parallel coding that .NET 4.0's task parallel library offers.

Will Rx.NET supersede TPL? Should it?

Answer (score 16):

In short, no.

The Task Parallel Library (TPL) provides provides distribution of work (**concurrency**), as well as the concurrent optimisation of larger work (**parallelism**) while abstracting the actual mechanism of work distribution (threads).

C# adds the `async` keyword to help manage **asynchrony** from a language level. Rx has already been updated to support this feature.

Rx provides a framework to **compose and manage asynchronous data streams** using standard operators. While there is some crossover in Rx's use of schedulers, this is only an abstraction. In fact, the recommended scheduler for parallelism is the `TaskScheduler`, which uses the TPL.

See also [Jeffrey van Gogh's response](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/43b60fc8-7835-4333-a4b9-870b5b32dbce) to the exact opposite question on the Rx forums.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138361/reactive-framework-vs-plinq-vs-task-parallel-library-vs-parallel-extensions) may be of use.

Comment: TPL isn't about parallelism, it's about concurrency.

Comment: @user - True, though PLINQ is part of TPL and it provides parallelism.

Comment: You must see the irony of that comment "Task Parallel Library isn't about Parallelism" ;-)

Comment: Old question but I don't think I can agree with this answer's premises (though the outcome is a different matter). For me, asynchrony is about generation of observables, and tasks can be considered observables too. So Rx is a different conceptual framework that offers a different terminology that encompasses everything TPL + async involves.